# Server Installation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have a real IP with dedicated server (Windows 2008 r2 with IIS) and a domain name. How could I bind that domain name to my server?

Comment: Is this honestly a professional quality/ level question?

Answer (score 0):

On your domain control panel (you can ask your registrar for this) set the A records to the ip address of your server. How you do this varies from registrar to registrar.

You can easily add a website in IIS and indicate the hostname (domain.com or www.domain.com) and u can easily get it to work.

Some hosts may have dns services where all u need to do on your domain control panel is to add the name server entries.

Hope this helps.